# Searching and sorting ranges in excel with toggle buttons

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, togglebutton, named-ranges

I have a spreadsheet containing ±100 named ranges (5 rows, 15 colums) which are sorted based on time.

My plan was to make toggle buttons to hide or unhide named ranges when they contain a certain value.

So when I select the toggle button for 'Opel' for instance, all the named ranges containing 'Opel' are displayed.  And when I select 'Opel' and 'Ford.  All the ranges containing 'Opel' and 'Ford' are displayed while also being able to sort the ranges in that view.

For the sorting I use the following code:

```
Sub SorterenOpdrachten()

Dim Detail As Worksheet
Dim I As Long
Dim ListRng As Range
Dim LijstWks As Worksheet
Dim NamedRng As Name
Dim R As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim SortWks As Worksheet


'Worksheet declareren als variabele
Set Detail = Worksheets("detail")
Set LijstWks = Worksheets("LijstWks")
Set SortWks = Worksheets("SortWks")

'Startrij voor de lijst instellen = Rij 1 fungeert als "hoofding"
R = 2



 'Ranges naar lijst kopiëren - Opdracht en uur
  For Each NamedRng In ActiveWorkbook.Names



    LijstWks.Cells(R, 1) = NamedRng.Name
    LijstWks.Cells(R, 2) = NamedRng.RefersToRange.Cells(1, 2)
    R = R + 1
  Next NamedRng

 'Ranges sorteren in de lijst
  R = R - 1
  Set ListRng = LijstWks.Range("A2").Resize(R - 1, 2)
  ListRng.Sort Key1:=ListRng.Cells(1, 2), Order1:=xlAscending



   'Ranges kopiëren naar SortWks
    R = 1
    For I = 1 To ListRng.Rows.Count
      Set Rng = ActiveWorkbook.Names(ListRng.Cells(I, 1).Text).RefersToRange
        Rng.Copy
        SortWks.Cells(R, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
      R = R + Rng.Rows.Count
    Next I

    'Opdrachten naar detail kopiëren
    R = 1
    Worksheets("SortWks").Range("A1:T499").Copy 
Worksheets("detail").Range("A5:T504")

Next intCounter
End Sub
```

This works fine.

But when I use it in combination with the toggle buttons it works too slow.

For the toggle buttons I use the following code:

```
 Sub Tegels()

Dim nm As Name

For Each nm In Application.Names
Range(nm).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next nm


If TglOpel Then
For Each nm In Application.Names
    If Application.CountIf(Range(nm), "*" & "Opel" & "*") Then 
Range(nm).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Next nm
End If

If TglChevrolet Then
For Each nm In Application.Names
    If Application.CountIf(Range(nm), "*" & "Chevrolet" & "*") Then 
Range(nm).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Next nm
End If

If TglFord Then
For Each nm In Application.Names
    If Application.CountIf(Range(nm), "*" & "Ford" & "*") Then 
 Range(nm).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Next nm
End If

If TglBuick Then
For Each nm In Application.Names
    If Application.CountIf(Range(nm), "*" & "Buick" & "*") Then 
Range(nm).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Next nm
End If

If TglDodge Then
For Each nm In Application.Names
    If Application.CountIf(Range(nm), "*" & "Dodge" & "*") Then 
Range(nm).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Next nm
End If


End Sub


Sub CheckTegels()

If TglOpel Then
Call Tegels
Exit Sub
Else
    If TglChevrolet Then
    Call Tegels
    Exit Sub
    Else
        If TglFord Then
        Call Tegels
        Exit Sub
        Else
            If TglBuick Then
            Call Tegels
            Exit Sub
            Else
                If TglDodge Then
                Call Tegels
                Exit Sub
                Else

                            Dim nm As Name

For Each nm In Application.Names
Range(nm).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Next nm


End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Any tips for speeding this process up?

Comment: Code optimization questions may be candidates for the [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than SO.